# Finding paths of length $n$ on a directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have the following directed graph

```
g = Graph[{DirectedEdge[v1, v1, a], DirectedEdge[v1, v1, OverBar[a]], 
   DirectedEdge[v1, v2, b], DirectedEdge[v2, v2, c], 
   DirectedEdge[v1, v3, OverBar[b]], 
   DirectedEdge[v3, v3, OverBar[c]]}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
  EdgeLabels -> "Index"]
```

First of all, I would prefer to label the edges with the tag of the directed edge, but I'm not sure how to do this.

The main question is, can Mathematica give me all possible paths of length $n$ on this graph starting from, say, $v1$? Here repeated edges and vertices are allowed $(1,5,\cdots,5)$ where we pass through the edge $5$  $n-1$ times would be a valid length $n$ path.

Comment: Tags are not for labelling. They are for distinguishing parallel edges. A use for labelling is IMO a misuse. That said, the EdgeLabels docs lists the `"EdgeTag"` specification.

Comment: "Path" usually means no repeating vertices. Thus this graph has no paths of length > 1. Please clarify if you allow repeating edges / vertices.

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201420/12

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for your answer, I have changed the question to be clear I allow repeating edges. I did see the answer in the comments but I had some problems with the package. The output gives KeyAbsent and I'm not really sure how to fix this.

Comment: If you have a specific problem with installing the package, please either post on https://igraph.discourse.group/ or ask a new question here and tag it with [tag:igraphm].

Comment: I have managed to get this working but it does not distinguish between the two loops on v1. Is there a way to incorporate this? This is necessary later work that I will be doing using these paths.

Comment: That answer only needs IGraphM for the adjacency list, you can achieve the same functionality with this: `adjassocdirected[g_] := 
 Association[(# -> 
      Sort@Cases[IncidenceList[g, #], # \[DirectedEdge] _][[All, 
        2]]) & /@ VertexList[g]]` and get `adj` using `adj = adjassocdirected[g]`, then the rest of that answer should solve your problem.

Comment: @math While I write up an answer, can you clarify what problems you had when trying to install the package?

Comment: @flinty IncidenceList does not take edge directions into account. This is why `IGAdjacencyList` exists, to provide features not present in `AdjacencyList`. I guess there should be an `IGIncidenceList` as well to simplify these tasks. Also be careful: Mathematica's handling of pattern matching when edge tags are present is also a bit inconsistent ...

Comment: @Szabolcs There no longer seems to be a problem with installing it, I think this was just my inexperience with using packages, this was the first time I have tried installing something into Mathematica.

Comment: @math Anyway, if you recall what you did wrong, feel free to drop me an email, so I can improve the installation instructions. This kind of feedback is always helpful. If you made a specific mistake, others are likely to make the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To visualize the edge tags, use `EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag"`.

This is a modification of the answer from https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201420/12. It returns the edges (not vertices) and it does not require the IGraph/M package.

Return the outgoing edges of a given vertex in a directed graph:

```
inclist[graph_?DirectedGraphQ][vertex_] := EdgeList[graph, DirectedEdge[vertex, __]]
```

Return the target vertex of a directed edge:

```
target[edge_] := edge[[2]]
```

One step of the iterative / recursive algorithm: take all outgoing edges of the last vertex, and follow each of them.

```
step[graph_][{most___, last_}] := {most, last, #} & /@ inclist[graph][target[last]]
```

Iterate this step as many times as we need:

```
Nest[Join @@ step[g] /@ # &, List /@ inclist[g][v1], 3 (* length of walks - 1 *)]
```

If you want *just* the tags, add this to the end:

```
Map[Last, %, {2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this!